# powershell if statements not giving predicted outcome

Tags: powershell, if-statement

I'm new to coding trying to figure out powershell and confused at If statements.
Trying to get this code so it'll create the job scheduling to run on login but it won't create it on the initial first run. I want to add in an if statement at the end to run the command to check if it exists on a desktop as some end users I want to deploy this too will already have it. But I'm unsure where the error lies with the code and how to address or simplify the code?
Any help would be greatly appreciated

```
$PathTest = Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\public\desktop\Google.lnk"
$Google = {$ShortcutPath = "C:\users\public\desktop\Google.lnk"
$IconLocation = "C:\windows\System32\SHELL32.dll"
$IconArrayIndex = 150
$Shortcut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "http://www.google.com"
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "$IconLocation, $IconArrayIndex"
$Shortcut.Save()
}
$Trigger = New-JobTrigger -AtLogOn -RandomDelay 00:00:30
Register-ScheduledJob -Trigger $Trigger -RunAs32 -ScriptBlock {$Google} -Name Google
If ($PathTest -is True) {
  $PathTest
  }  Else {
  $Google
}
```

Comment: ```Test-Path``` returns a boolean value (i.e. ```$true``` or ```$false```) - see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/test-path?view=powershell-7.2#description. - so your conditional expression can just be ```if( $PathTest ) { … }```.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a wrong if operator:
`-is` is used for checking types:

```
if ( $value -is [type] )
{
     # do something
}
```

For a boolean check you can just use:

```
$condition = $true
if ( $condition ) # check for $true
{
     Write-Output "The condition was true"
}

$condition = $false
if ( !$condition ) # check for $false
{
     Write-Output "The condition was also true by inverting with not operator"
}
```

[MS Docs PowerShell IF-Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-if?view=powershell-7.2)

Comment: So I currently have the code setup as 
$PathTest = $false
if ($PathTest)
{
    $Google
}

but its not running as intended, changing the boolean to $true works but I am hoping to get the code to run when it comes back as false

Comment: this won't work: with `if ($PathTest) {}` you check for `$true`... For check for `$false` you have to add an inverting: `if ( -not $value ){}` or `if ( !$value ){}` then it will work! - I adjusted my answer for the false check case

Comment: I've got it set as that now but returning back as the condition is always true regardless of what the result is. 

$PathTest = $false
if ( !$PathTest ) # check for $false
{
     $Google
}
$PathTest = $true
if ( $PathTest ) # check for $true
{
     Write-Output "The condition was true"
}

Comment: @Callistis can you add your current code then I can check it out

Comment: $PathTest = Test-Path -Path "C:\Users\public\desktop\google.lnk"

$Google = {$ShortcutPath = "C:\users\public\desktop\Igoogle.lnk"
$IconLocation = "C:\windows\System32\SHELL32.dll"
$IconArrayIndex = 150
$Shell = New-Object -ComObject ("WScript.Shell")
$Shortcut = $Shell.CreateShortcut($ShortcutPath)
$Shortcut.TargetPath = "http://www.google.com"
$Shortcut.IconLocation = "$IconLocation, $IconArrayIndex"
$Shortcut.Save()
}

$PathTest = $false
if ( !$PathTest )
{
    $Google
}
$PathTest = $True
if ($PathTest)
{
Write-Output "The filepath is true"
}
@droebi thank you so much

Comment: https://tio.run/##fZFPa8IwGIfv@RTvQg8V1rIpuww8DBmbIHNQh5deYvpqM2NTknSdiJ@9S/9Mq4xdkrzJ@zzJj@SqRG1SlLKqvHdm0wUaC2Oop6CuoR3p5DH@MK41zouVFDxO0GytyuONUhuJocy2lHgvTeHwA/GiVGnLC9vg40ZQ/CWY9gxAvClX2UxxZoXKOqwUWaJKE0d7Y3E3GsbR6/NsNhqGiZS0JZ60ZvtpluC3Y@4f7urrXSZXvGEZzFefyC0EE7Xrlj5dRlyL3IZNHx2c3@uYFg4nGpnF333/IlEPCBdMb/CUs4vD1Y72eq5jXeS8hasQfTJiX@gPyJH0v8dbM2kQiFiDDzfnkwGQA5z@gSy1sBjMC5u7XHSRIqyFxLx@qTDQOCg5wqXa6qIzn7Yb7f@ymqJwrKof

Answer (score 1):

The `if` statement is using wrong [operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2). `-is` is used to test object types, not logical equality which is `-eq`. In addition, the [boolean](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_booleans?view=powershell-7.2) true is `$true`